# undefined method `deliveries' for ActionMailer::Base:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I started randomly getting the following stack trace in my project [on this repo](https://github.com/massmetrics/app) when running tests.  My buddy forked and cloned and he doesn't get the error.  I also have other projects that call the deliveries method and they have no problems.  I have tried deleting the file and re cloning and it still doesn't work.  I honestly have no idea where to start.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `deliveries' for ActionMailer::Base:Class
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionmailer-4.1.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:553:in `method_missing'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionmailer-4.1.1/lib/action_mailer/test_case.rb:59:in `initialize_test_deliveries'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:349:in `run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:410:in `block in run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:410:in `each'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:410:in `run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:485:in `run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:340:in `run_before_example'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:147:in `block in run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `call'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Procsy>'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:430:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `call'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Procsy>'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:432:in `run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:485:in `run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:303:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:145:in `run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:494:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `map'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:457:in `run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `block in run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `map'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `map'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block in run_specs'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:54:in `report'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
     # /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
     # 
     #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
     #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
     #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
```

Comment: it should be .deliver and not .deliveries

Comment: could you remove the git tag ? the fact that you provide a link to your github repo does not make the question "related to git" at all, thanks

Comment: @Mandeep  I want to count the deliveries.  This works in at least 3 other projects that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was my gemset.  I am not sure how it happened because it was seemingly in the middle of writing code in a test but I installed a new gemset and all is good.  Thanks for anyone who took the time to read this and or edit my post.